# How can I reposition the widget on a small (mobile) screen when using the Bootstrap-DateTime-Picker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

When it is shown on a small screen (mobile in portrait), the widget displays so that the left portion of the widget is off the screen (when all the way zoomed out). There is room on the screen so that if it was offset ~40px to the right, it would fit on the screen, but I can't figure out how to reposition it at all, let alone when only on a small screen. Any suggestions on how to do this?

I am using the Bootstrap-datetimepicker-rails gem to integrate it into my app. I am using Rails 4.1, Ruby 2.1 and Bootstrap 3. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For `bootstrap-datetimepicker`, take a look at the [widget positioning](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#widgetpositioning) parameter, it allows you to position the date picker relative to the trigger element.

In this case of `bootstrap-datepicker`, a similar option is called [orientation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/stable/options.html#orientation).

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to move the widget by X pixels left or right?

Comment: I don't see this option in the documentation. You can take a look at the CSS code [here](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/tree/master/less) and see if you can tweak it. But, usually changing the orientation has always been enough for me to look ok on any screen size, you should give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out!

Comment: Please check the edit, sorry, originally I mistook `bootstap-datetimepicker` (what you use) for `bootstrap-datepicker`